# C: sort values into a static list

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, static

I have the task to paste results of an exam into a static list sorted by highest to lowest.

I initialize a list with the results of the examination and declare a "empty static list". 
With the function `insertSortArray(...)` I want to paste the result into the static list.

I am wondering why the sequence of "noten" is changed after the second printf of "noten". 
Can this somebody explain to me? 
Thats one point. 
The other point ist that I am struggling with algorithm to sort the values. 
I know I could copy the values and then program a bubble sort, but is there a way to sort it from the one list to the other?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insertSortArray(float *array, float *list, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        list[i] = array[i];
    }
}


int main()
{
    float noten[] = { 4.0,
                      1.3, 
                      1.0, 
                      5.0, 
                      2.3};

    float statList[] = { 0 };
    int length = sizeof(noten) / sizeof(float);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", noten[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%f\n", noten[1]);
    printf("\n");

    insertSortArray(noten, statList, length);

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\t", noten[i]);
        printf("%f\n", statList[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%f\n", noten[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nit-pick: Always use unsigned types to store size of types. Replace `int length` by `size_t length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float statList[] = { 0 };` declares an array with just *one* element that is initialized to zero. That is *too small* to copy your static array to.

Use:

```
float statList[5] = { 0 };
```

This declares an array of 5 elements of which the first is explicitly initialized to zero (and because not enough initializers are provided to initialize the whole array, all remaining elements are set to zero).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.